# Nginx not serving static files (JS, CSS, Images, etc.)

Tags: nginx

**I SOLVED IT WITH THIS ANSWER:**
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/mount-cifs-network-drive-write-permissions-and-chown

---

I am trying to setup my new internal server with a Ubuntu on a Parallel Desktop on a Mac Studo M2 Ultra (ARM64). I am using the same (excluding the IP, of course) mysite.conf from my old server (that works fine). I tryed every possible solution for 2 days and nothing works!

The PHP files are serving without problem, but all the static files fail without any visible error (if I access the file link directly, the browser simple stay in the same page and nothing happend).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 192.168.1.171:80;
    #server_name _;


    root /var/www/html/mysite.com/public;
    index index.html index.php;

    client_max_body_size 64M;

    location / {

        if ($request_uri !~ ^/ajax/) {
            #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?do=/$1 last;
            rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?do=/$1;

        }

        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        
    }

    location ~* \.(css|map|js|eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico|mp4|webm|ogv|pdf|webp)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        access_log off;
        expires 1d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $args;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$args;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/api/index.php;
    }

    location /endpoint/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /endpoint/index.php?$args;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/endpoint/index.php;
    }

    location /dcrt {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/dc-realtime.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a Link to one of the files and the output of the NGINX error.log configured using `error_log /path/to/error.log error`;

Comment: Hi, @TimoStark. It's normal jpgs, pngs, css, js, etc. files. There's nothing relevant it error log. It's something like:

192.168.1.132 - - [19/Feb/2024:08:59:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 15702 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0"

When I try to access directly access static files, the browser ignore.

Comment: Please update the Post with an screenshot of your Browser-Dev-Tools and the Network-Tab while trying to access static file. The access-log you shared just shows an GET Request to `/` which will be rewriten on the nignx site.

Comment: @TimoStark when I access http://192.168.1.171/ I can see the regular processed PHP without images and styles. I can also access http://192.168.1.171/test/test.php. If I try to directly access any static file the browser ignore it, for example http://192.168.1.171/favicon.png. Devtools stay complety empty and nothing show on the access-log. The only lines in it is the ones I show earlier.

(I tryed in all devices, browsers, Ad-blocker off, etc. I also tryed all possible solutions I found online, nothing works.

Comment: So IF the Devtools are empty and the Network-Tab IS NOT! showing a HTTP Connection to the Backend thats your reason why NGINX can't deliver any files and why the logs are empty. If there is nothing in the Network Tab in your Browser Devtools when requesting `http://192.168.1.171/favicon.png` this is an issue of your Frontend Application. Send a CURL requset using the  command line to the server and see what changes. Elimante the Browser as a potential Problem.

Comment: @TimoStark that's the strange part. wget http://192.168.1.171/favicon.png return: 2024-02-21 18:14:26 (0.00 B/s) - Connection closed at byte 0. Retrying. ||| http://192.168.1.171/favicon.png -> curl: (18) transfer closed with 34527 bytes remaining to read. I am really don't know where to go next to solve this. I tryed everything.